# IntelliJ uses wrong encoding

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I am using intelliJ 2017.3 CE, I have a strange behaviour which i cannot resolve although I tried everything I found to that topic.

For simplicity I extracted the root cause of my problem, IntelliJ does not use the desired encoding in my case UTF-8. Here is my simple class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("äüö");
}
```

running this class leads to the following output:

```
13:03:47: Executing task 'StringTest2.main()'...
:core:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:core:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:core:classes UP-TO-DATE
:core:compileTestJava
:core:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:core:testClasses
:core:StringTest2.main()
Ã¤Ã¼Ã¶


BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s
5 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 3 up-to-date
13:03:49: Task execution finished 'StringTest2.main()'.
```

Here you can see the encoding of the file

[image]

here are the settings of my intellij installation
[image]

What I tried:

- added to my gradle.properties: systemProp.file.encoding=utf-8
- created a run configuration for that class where i defined jvm settings: -Dfile.encoding=utf-8
- executed a testcase where this problem originally occured from command line (gradle) but the error also occured
- Tested the class on a different pc (mac) with intellij and there the log out was as expected.

I dont know what else I can try.

Comment: somethere your UTF-8 string was converted to ISO-8859-1 encoding. Possible your console encoding is ISO-8859-1

Answer (score 1):

[The console still uses the platform encoding](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-output-encoding.html).

Use

```
-Dconsole.encoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: I have added this to the shard build process VM options but it does not change the output. Also i tried it as JVM Options for the run configuration but also no change.

Comment: Try `"\u00E4\u00F6\u00FC"`. Should this work, then indeed the editor is using UTF-8 (we knew already), bu the compiler javac uses the platform encoding.